# How do I show the numbers I entered in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program where at the end I have to display the numbers I entered and the maximum and minimum of those entered numbers. However I'm running into a little problem, here is my code,

```
import java.util.*;

public class question3controlstructures {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        int numberEntered;
        int numbersinput = 0;
        String answer ="";
        double sum = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            numberEntered = in.nextInt();
            numbersinput ++;
            System.out.println("do you want to enter another number?");
            answer = in.next();
            sum = sum + numberEntered;
        } while (answer.equals("yes"));

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + sum/numbersinput);
        System.out.println(numberEntered);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question?  If you want to remember the numbers you entered, you will need an array or some sort of collection.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to echo them as they are entered, you can use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer List will keep the original sequence so your comment should be *Assuming you want to echo them as they are entered, you can use a List*

Comment: @AniketSahrawat No - If all the user wants to do is echo them as they are entered (within the `do-while` loop), then they don't need to do anything. If they wish to "remember" what was entered at a later stage, then they need some kind of `List`, as it's size is dynamic

Comment: Suppose the problem is that you cannot get entered numbers. That because your numberEntered variable is integer variable that holds scalar value. To get number array you have to produce number Array. For Example int[] numberEnteredArray; And assign all the input numbers into the array. You can get numbersinput count by getting array length. To print entered numbers you have to run array inside a loop such as for or foreach or while or until.

Answer (score 0):

The above comment are absolutely useful. However, here is little code

```
package com.mars;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question3controlstructures {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.print("Enter integers please ");
    System.out.println("(EOF or non-integer to terminate): ");

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        list.add(scan.nextInt());
    }

    Integer[] nums = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + nums[i];

    }
    System.out.println("sum..." + sum);
    System.out.println("The average is: " + sum / i);
    System.out.println(i);

    System.out.println("max.. "+Collections.max(list));
    System.out.println("min.. "+Collections.min(list));
    scan.close();
    }

   }
```

As suggent in comments , you need a list to store the multiple numbered entered.

Comment: You don't need a list to calculate the sum & average, by the way. Definitely don't need an array from that list

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks for the comment , i will look into that. Just on my mind , if he need to display which series of multiple number entered , can we do this without list or array ?

Comment: I guess he was just pointing out that the use of an additional array to sum up the list values is unnecessary. Nothing wrong with storing the user input in a list.

Answer (score 0):

just compare the min and max every time you enter a number

```
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE

    int numberEntered;
    int numbersinput = 0;
    String answer ="";
    double sum = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        numberEntered = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("YOU HAVE ENTERED: " + numbersEntered);
        if (min > numberEntered) min = numberEntered;
        if (max < numberEntered) max = numberEntered;

        numbersinput ++;
        sum = sum + numberEntered;

        System.out.println("do you want to enter another number?");
        answer = in.next();
    } while (answer.equals("yes"));

    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
    System.out.println("The average is: " + sum/numbersinput);
    System.out.println(numberEntered);

    //you can print your min max here.
```

Answer (score 0):

The [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) class together with Java 8's Stream API may be less verbose than dealing with min, max, sum and avg calculation manually.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Get user input.
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        // No user friendly way to gather user input, improve!
        numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    // Transform input to statistics.
    IntSummaryStatistics stats = numbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer.intValue()));

    // Print statistics.
    String jointNumbers = numbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    System.out.printf("You entered %d numbers: %s\n, stats.getCount(), jointNumbers);
    System.out.println("Min: " + stats.getMin());
    System.out.println("Max: " + stats.getMax());
    System.out.println("Sum: " + stats.getMax());
    System.out.println("Avg: " + stats.getAverage());
}
```